# Accessing Geolocation detail from images - ios 8.3

Tags: ios, geolocation

I'm total newbie in IOS so I have no idea what I'm missing but I've gone through [this](http://oleb.net/blog/2011/09/accessing-image-properties-without-loading-the-image-into-memory/) website to fetch location detail from image but no luck.
It will be great if anyone can help.
following code is inside *didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo* function of *UIImagepicker*

```
NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                             [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO], (NSString *)kCGImageSourceShouldCache,
                             nil];
     NSLog(@"Image properties %@",imageProperties);
    NSData *data=UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 0);
    CGImageSourceRef source=CGImageSourceCreateWithData((CFDataRef)data, NULL);
    CFDictionaryRef imageProperties = CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(source, 0, (CFDictionaryRef)options);


    CFDictionaryRef gps = CFDictionaryGetValue(imageProperties, kCGImagePropertyGPSDictionary);
    NSLog(@"GPS %@",gps);
    if (gps) {
        NSString *latitudeString = (NSString *)CFDictionaryGetValue(gps, kCGImagePropertyGPSLatitude);
        NSString *latitudeRef = (NSString *)CFDictionaryGetValue(gps, kCGImagePropertyGPSLatitudeRef);
        NSString *longitudeString = (NSString *)CFDictionaryGetValue(gps, kCGImagePropertyGPSLongitude);
        NSString *longitudeRef = (NSString *)CFDictionaryGetValue(gps, kCGImagePropertyGPSLongitudeRef);
        NSLog(@"GPS Coordinates: %@ %@ / %@ %@", longitudeString, longitudeRef, latitudeString, latitudeRef);
    }
```

And Output :

```
Image properties
{
ColorModel = RGB;
Depth = 8;
Orientation = 6;
PixelHeight = 720;
PixelWidth = 960;
"{Exif}" =     {
    ColorSpace = 1;
    PixelXDimension = 960;
    PixelYDimension = 720;
};
"{JFIF}" =     {
    DensityUnit = 0;
    JFIFVersion =         (
        1,
        0,
        1
    );
    XDensity = 72;
    YDensity = 72;
};
"{TIFF}" =     {
    Orientation = 6;
};
}
GPS (null)
```

[Pic of Image *GetInfo*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Alb1i.png)

So Image does have location attached but while fetching,it shows null for geolocation.

Thank You.

Comment: Are you sure your image actually has coordinates? Your output suggests it doesn't...

Comment: Yep I'm sure I have location coordinates.I have seen the location detail in image properties of photo album.